# Cypher aggregate over subset of paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregate

I have the following graph, and am interested in getting the sum of all amounts for the leaf node, starting from a1.

[image]

However, with cypher it takes all paths into account and the end result is 24 instead of 12 using a SUM query.
E.g.

```
match (:A {name:'a1'})<-[:BA]-(:B)-[:BC]->(c:C)-[cd:CD]->(d:D)
return d.name, SUM(cd.amount)
```

What should my query look like?

Here's the cypher to create the graph.

nodes:

```
create (a1:A {name:'a1'}), (b1:B {name:'b1'}), (b2:B {name:'b2'}),
(c1:C {name:'c1'}), (c2:C {name:'c2'}), (d1:D {name:'d1'})
```

rels:

```
match (a1:A {name:'a1'}), (b1:B {name:'b1'}), (b2:B {name:'b2'}), 
(c1:C {name:'c1'}), (c2:C {name:'c2'}), (d1:D {name:'d1'})
merge (a1)<-[:BA]-(b1)
merge (a1)<-[:BA]-(b2)
merge (b1)-[:BC]->(c1)
merge (b1)-[:BC]->(c2)
merge (b2)-[:BC]->(c1)
merge (b2)-[:BC]->(c2)
merge (c1)-[:CD {amount: 5}]->(d1)
merge (c2)-[:CD {amount: 7}]->(d1)
```

Comment: Try replacing "return d.name as dname, SUM(cd.amount)" with "with d.name AS dname, DISTINCT(cd) as cdd RETURN dname, SUM(cdd.amount)"

Comment: Thanks @TimKuehn. looks like 'distinct' needs to be the first keyword after 'with'. So this works: 
   match (:A {name:'a1'})<-[:BA]-(:B)-[:BC]->(c:C)-[cd:CD]->(d:D)
   with distinct d.name AS dname, cd
   RETURN dname, SUM(cd.amount) as total

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TimKuehn for the 'distinct' hint.

This query works:

```
MATCH (:A {name:'a1'})<-[:BA]-(:B)-[:BC]->(c:C)-[cd:CD]->(d:D) 
WITH DISTINCT d.name AS dname, cd 
RETURN dname, SUM(cd.amount) as total
```